# Corona SDK. How can I read SMS from inbox?

Tags: sms, coronasdk

Corona SDK. How can I read SMS from inbox?

is it possible?

or The way to read sms is only in android SDK??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not possible as of now!

In iphone, you can open the sms app though using

```
system.openURL("Sms://")
```